# a bizarre mistake-----InvalidArgumentError: slice index -1 of dimension 0 out of bounds.（）

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

My computer is installed with win10, tf-nightly-2.0-preview==2.0.0dev20190926，python3.7&python3.6.8

Tensorflow standard template: https://tensorflow.google.cn/tutorials/load_data/images#setup

When I run the tensorflow standard template, I get an error in

```
for image, label in labeled_ds.take(1):
    print("Image shape: ", image.numpy().shape)
    print("Label: ", label.numpy())
```

the error message:

```
InvalidArgumentError: slice index -1 of dimension 0 out of bounds. [[{{node strided_slice}}]]
Encountered when executing an operation using EagerExecutor.
```

This error cancels all future operations and poisons their output tensors.

However, in google colab I installed tf-nightly-2.0-preview==2.0.0dev20190926, python==3.6,
Running the code but it runs fine without errors

If I want to run this standard template code on my computer, how should I modify it?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this was a problem with `tf.strings.split` within the provided `get_label` method. On Colab splitting on a single forward slash worked, but on my local Windows machine I needed to split on a backslash.

So if your Colab code looks like this:

```py
def get_label(file_path):
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, '/')
    return parts[-2] == settings.CLASS_NAMES
```

Change it to look like this when running locally:

```py
def get_label(file_path):
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, '\\')
    return parts[-2] == settings.CLASS_NAMES
```